# Js image link codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter ,
My base url is:`http://localhost/C_I`
My problem is when I am using base url in json image is not loading 
includes css,image and js files are working

```
'<?= base_url('public/js/jquery.js')?>'
```

It is working but

```
slides : [
      {image :'`<?= base_url('public/images/1.jpg')?>`'};
      {image :'`<?= base_url('public/images/2.jpg')?>`'};
      {image :'`<?= base_url('public/images/3.jpg')?>`'};

     ]
```

`base_url('public/images/1.jpg')` inside slides image not working...

Please help me

Comment: Is your images folder is inside public folder,

Comment: please write echo before base_url('public/images/1.jpg')

Comment: @Rishi `<?=` is short for `<?php echo`. @selva where are you outputting those paths, inside a php file or a js file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..this is inside the js file..

Comment: Your php scripts not gonna execute if you place it in a js file.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
slides : [
  {image :"<?php base_url('public/images/1.jpg')?>"};
  {image :"<?php base_url('public/images/2.jpg')?>"};
  {image :"<?php base_url('public/images/3.jpg')?>"};
 ]
```

Comment: jQuery(function($){
  $.supersized({
   slide_interval          :   4000,  
   transition              :   1, 
   transition_speed  : 900,                      
   slide_links    : false, 
   slides      :   [ 
           {image : '<?php echo base_url('/public/images/1.jpg');?>'};
           {image : '<?php echo base_url('/public/images/2.jpg');?>'};
           {image : '<?php echo base_url('/public/images/3.jpg');?>'};
          
          
          
          ]
     
  });
 }); This is my js...

Comment: change this ';' to ','...slides : [ {image : '<?php echo base_url('/public/images/1.jpg');?>'}, {image : '<?php echo base_url('/public/images/2.jpg');?>'}, {image : '<?php echo base_url('/public/images/3.jpg');?>'}; ]

Answer (score 0):

Your php scripts not executed/work in js/css files. You have to do 1 thing that just give the absolute path to your image or globally define the base_url like

```
var baseUrl = "http://localhost/test/index.php/";
```

Then use this jquery variable anywhere in your file.

I hope this will help you in future.

Comment: Thanks for your helps but still Iam facing that issue..<br>But when I go to the inspect element or view page source it is showing correct path ...